# Template doesn't get compiled after being added to the page dynamically

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Edit: I found the real problem and I'm working to find a solution for it. The problem is basically the fact that i angular is not able to detect the dependencies in the controller which is loaded after the on-click-event. So my controller function won't be executed.

I'm recently trying to get deeper into angularJS. Therefore I was creating some applications which were builtin on different pages. Now I tried to bring them together on one single page. Since I had those multiple apps I had to bootstrap them manually. Even thought everything works fine I want to make the whole page into a single app. And this is the point at which the problem occurs.
There were three different apps on my page: The first two are directly loaded together with the the page. But the third one gets dynamically loaded by adding a div with an on-click-event. The event also loads the specific scripts like controllers and services. For some reason the loaded template isn't compiled and the raw angular expressions are displayed on the page.

Edit:
This is the part in my php-programm where the scripts for the app itself are added to the page:

```
$jScripts = 
'<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WEBURI . '/js/select/core/core.js"></script>'."\n".
'<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WEBURI . '/js/select/core/services/configFactory.js"></script>';
```

The core.js scripts defines the angular.module with its dependencies.

The specific spricts are added in the php Viewscript which is called by starting the click-event:

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WEBURI . '/js/select/core/services/organisationCiFactory.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WEBURI . '/js/select/organisationCiSelect/controllers/selectController.js"></script>
';
```

The controller looks like this:

```
angular
    .module('cidb.core')
    .controller('cidb.core.organisationCiSelectCtrl',
        [
            '$scope',
            'cidb.core.Config',
            'cidb.core.OrganisationCi',
            SelectCtrl
        ]
    );
```

The part in my php Viewscript:

```
<div ng-cloak="ng-cloak">
<div ng-controller="cidb.core.organisationCiSelectCtrl" >
    //My-Template
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Please add some code to help us better understand your issue.

Comment: I tried to add some of the code

Answer (score 0):

You should not delay scripts loading in angularJS, link it directly to your `index.html`

In production, you might want to minify your source code into a single js file

Comment: I tried to link it directly so it would be loaded after the page finished loading, but it's still not working. My template still doesn't get rendered. Could it be that the addition of the div to my page is causing the error because the script is execute before?

Comment: Which part of your code added the div? it should be angular JS not php

Comment: ALL templating should be done in angularJS, your PHP should only provide JSON data